# Forgot to include passport information

Tags: passports

I forgot to enter my passport number while booking a ticket from MakeMyTrip app and my booking has been confirmed. What should I do? At check in, will they add the passport information?

Comment: You can usually just log into the airline's web site using your last name and the booking code and add any information the airlines needs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Airline agents always check your passport when you check in for any international flight where you require it.  They update the document details at that time.